# Postgres: How to populate an array after insert

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures, insert

Imagine we have a simple table

```
create table a (id serial, data text);
```

and the following function:

```
create or replace function f()
returns SETOF int As
$BODY$
DECLARE
  l_arr int[];
BEGIN

  insert into a(data) 
  values ('a') 
  returning array_agg(data) into l_arr; --THIS DOES NOT WORK

  RETURN l_arr;

END;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql' VOLATILE SECURITY DEFINER
  COST 100
```

How one may gather inserted values into an array in the same SQL statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears, that it is possible to use RETURN QUERY without intermediate array:

```
create or replace function f()
returns SETOF int As
$BODY$
BEGIN
  RETURN QUERY
  insert into a(data) 
  values ('a') 
  returning id;
END;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql' VOLATILE SECURITY DEFINER
  COST 100
```

Comment: This will return a set, not an array, so this is not a good answer for your question :)

Comment: @dezso it is the answer because the function in the question aims to return set ;)